# Modal z-index over external content peeks through?

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I'm creating a modal dialog using jQuery. The code inserts jQuery into the site by means of a bokmarklet, and runs a script that creates a [modal dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog). The problem is that some site content always seems to peek through the gray modal, even in Chrome or Firefox. Is there a way to get around it?

[image]

*The gray part in the bottom is the modal. The logo peeks through.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to make every dom object on the client page to have a z-index of 1, or lower than the z-index of the modal. Some browsers take into consideration the relative differences of z-indices, so that is crucial.

```
$("div").each(function() {
  $(this).css("z-index", "1");
});
```

works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a modal overlay and a modal window? I would set your z-index on them extremely high. Since it sounds like you are adding HTML into existing sites, it's hard to say what elements they have set a z-index to and at what level, so best bet it set your z-index to something like 100000.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I heard somewhere that z-index is relative. Do I have to set the existing HTML z-index?